# collectionView use estimatedItemSize self-sizing then display ok ,when collectionView reloaddata,colllectionview will scrollToTop

Tags: ios

I use below code to resize collection view cells that works fine.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:layoutAttributes];


    CGRect newFrame = attributes.frame;


    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize desiredSize = [self systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];

    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, desiredSize.height);
    attributes.frame = newFrame;
    return attributes;
}
```

But when I use or call `[collectionView reloadData]`
 the collection view is scrolled automaticaly to the top of the collection view.

Please help me out with it.

Comment: Please provide some more information, for better understanding this question is not properly formatted and also did not provide proper information.

Comment: i use UICollectionViewFlowLayout estimatedItemSize to autolayout Self sizing cells,and cell display ok,but when perform [collectionView reloadData],collectionView will auto scrollToTop,thanks